# How can I realise this design in code?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am currently designing a one-page website, and I would like some of the pages to have one column with text and one with an image. However the image should 'fill' the browser window size for which I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( ".screenheight" ).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css({'min-height':($(window).height())+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $this.css({'min-height':($(window).height())+'px'});
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

This works, however I cannot find out how to still align the column with the text, to the menu (like on pages `with width: 960px` and `margin: 0 auto;`)

This is an image from the design I'm trying to realise:
[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNFUR.jpg)

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly it is you need, or what the problem is. can you provide link to full example page?

Comment: Can you provide the html and css you have now too? What should happen when the image doesn't exactly fit the space, do you want to crop part of it?

Comment: With Bootstrap you could just define 2 column and fill them no ?

Comment: Have you had a look at fullPage.js - http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ - might be easier than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I just want to create a design that looks just like this: http://imgur.com/OIaYV1a

So far i've created a column on the left for text and one for the image on the right. I want the image on the right to fit the div and the browser window. I can't figure out how to still align the content in the left column with "Claudia Couwenbergh" . Just like it's aligned in the design.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery to get the height of the window you should look into using CSS's viewport lengths `vh` & `vw` to set things to be the size of the viewport.

This should easily give you the full page look. However, I am still a bit unclear as to what your issue is with the column and the menu.

More info about these units here: [Viewport Relative Lengths](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Comment: Hello and thank you for the link, I will check that out.

I would like to align the h1 (in this case 'Biografie') to the menu, so like the menu, I used width:960px; and margin: 0 auto;

but now that I actually want to fill the screen with the image, I can't put it inside the div because it will center itself and thus the image will not fill the screen and white bars will appear.

I hope you understand, it is difficult to explain. I have included an image in which the guidelines represent the 960px width, with margin: 0 auto;

http://imgur.com/JCOEYdY

Comment: @Victor So, correct me if I'm wrong, you want the picture to take up the whole width of the page, but the column of text in the center of that? Could you maybe create a picture that shows what you want it to look like?

Comment: yes you are right! I want the layout to look just like this: http://imgur.com/OIaYV1a

I tried creating one column on the left for the text, and one for the image, but I want the text to be aligned with "Claudia Couwenbergh" in the menu.

Comment: @Victor what does the page look like now?